# Wired LAN is being connected, but can't access internet

Tags: 14.04, networking, dual-boot, internet, lan

I live in a hostel. We have a LAN network and ports in each room. To access internet, we need to enter specific IPV4 settings. I have the necessary settings, and on connecting the cable, it shows that LAN is connected, but there is no Internet access, whereas when I connect other laptops to the same port using the same settings, it works. I am running Windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04 as dual boot. I have tried to find the solution online, but none worked for me. Wifi works fine.

The following is output of ifconfig-

```
rishabh@RISHABH-PC:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:de:f1:d7:e9:4a  
          inet addr:10.32.3.100  Bcast:10.32.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f2de:f1ff:fed7:e94a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:240 (240.0 B)  TX bytes:557364 (557.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:51630 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:51630 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4085191 (4.0 MB)  TX bytes:4085191 (4.0 MB)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.. :)

Comment: So does Windows work fine, but Ubuntu has the problems? Or do both not work

Comment: Do you have problem on both the win 7 and Ubuntu partitions of this laptop?

Comment: Where did you add the IPv4 settings? In Network Manager? Did you add address, netmask, gateway _AND_ DNS nameservers?

Comment: after you configure the network in network-manager, you have to reconnect to the network to apply the settings. try using a dns server like 8.8.4.4 or something like that

Comment: It doesn't work in either of them, Win7 and ubuntu.

Comment: I added the IPv4 settings in network manager. Yeah, i added the address, netmask, gateway and DNS nameservers @chili555

Answer (score 0):

This shows that the hostel does not support DHCP, so you probably do not have a **default route** set up. Type:

```
 ip route
```

to see your routing. You should see something like:

```
$ ip route
default via 10.32.3.100 dev eth0  proto static 
10.32.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.32.3.100  metric 1
```

If you do, then this answer is inapplicable, ignore it. If you do not have a "`default via`" entry, do

If they gave you a "router address" use it, otherwise do:

```
$ arp -an
```

to list the IP addresses and MAC addresses on your Ethernet segment, and pick one. Use either the "router address" or one picked from `arp -an`,

```
$ sudo ip route add default via <IP Address> dev eth0
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it has a default via entry.